# Example of Silverlight 5 RIA services authentication with active directory

Tags: silverlight, authentication, active-directory, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I'm looking for example of Silverlight 5 RIA services with authentication with active directory,

that ***can be downloaded and that works***

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a complete downloadable example. The easiest way is to create a new Silverlight Business Application and then make the following changes to the 3 files specified (Web.config, App.xaml.cs, User.cs):

**App.xaml.cs**

- *Comment out (or remove) the following lines*:

  //webContext.Authentication = new FormsAuthentication();
- *Uncomment the following lines*:

  webContext.Authentication = new WindowsAuthentication();

**User.cs**

- *add the [ProfileUsage...] statement to the public partial class user so it looks like the following*:

public partial class User : UserBase

```
{
    [ProfileUsage(IsExcluded=true)]   ///NEEDED FOR WINDOWS/ACTIVE DIRECTORY LOGON
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
}
```

**Web.config:**

Comment out (or remove) the following lines:

```
<!--<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".AuthenticationTest_ASPXAUTH" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>-->
```

Uncomment the following lines:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Comment out (or remove) the following lines:

```
    <!--<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <properties>
        <add name="FriendlyName" />
      </properties>
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>-->

  <!--<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>-->

Add the following lines:

  <system.serviceModel> 
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="winAuthBasicHTTPBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AuthenticationTest.Web.AuthenticationServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticationTest.Web.AuthenticationServiceBehavior" name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="winAuthBasicHTTPBinding" 
                  contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService">
        </endpoint>
    </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```